# Why does Tesseract not recognize the text on the licence plate while easyocr does?

Tags: python, opencv, python-tesseract

I am working on automatic licence plate recognition. I could cropped the [Plate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHQ5q.jpg) from inital image. But, Tesseract does not recognize the text on this plate while easyocr does. What is the reason? Thanks in advance for the answers. I used the code extract the plate from a car and recognize.

```
import cv2 as cv
import pytesseract
import imutils
import numpy as np
import easyocr
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

img3 = cv.imread("4.png")
cv.imshow("Car", img3)
img3 = cv.cvtColor(img3, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
gray = cv.cvtColor(img3, cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

bfilter_img3 = cv.bilateralFilter(img3, 11, 17, 17)
edged_img3 = cv.Canny(bfilter_img3, 30, 200)

keypoints = cv.findContours(edged_img3.copy(), cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = imutils.grab_contours(keypoints)
contours = sorted(contours, key=cv.contourArea, reverse=True)[:10]

location = None
for contour in contours:
    approx = cv.approxPolyDP(contour, 10, True)
    if len(approx) == 4:
        location = approx
        break

mask = np.zeros(gray.shape, np.uint8)
new_img = cv.drawContours(mask, [location], 0, 255, -1)
new_img = cv.bitwise_and(img3, img3, mask=mask)

print(location)
cv.imshow("Plate", new_img)


(x,y)=np.where(mask==255)
(x1,y1)=(np.min(x),np.min(y))
(x2,y2)=(np.max(x),np.max(y))
cropped_img=gray[x1:x2+1, y1:y2+1]
ret, cropped_img=cv.threshold(cropped_img,127,255,cv.THRESH_BINARY)
cv.imshow("Plate3", cropped_img)
cropped_img = cv.resize(cropped_img, None, fx=2/3, fy=2/3, interpolation=cv.INTER_AREA)
#"cropped_img= the plate image in the question"***********
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(cropped_img)
print("Text by tesseract: ",text)

""""
reader=easyocr.Reader(['en'])
text2=reader.readtext(cropped_img)
print(text2)
"""
k = cv.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Please add the code you are trying.

Comment: None of these modules are perfect.  You didn't show us any code, so we can't tell whether you are using Tesseract correctly, but it's possible `easyocr` just handles this case better.

Comment: Sorry, i added.

Comment: I used 4 plates, tesseract recognized just 1. The plate in the image in the question is very clear as for me.

Comment: They have different algorithm to detect texts, try to paste that text to a blank paper and try teeseract, it ll probably work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm kind of curious why did you use `bilateralFilter`, `Canny`, `findContours` etc.? Did you see the result of each method?

Anyway, if you set the `page-segmentation-mode` to [6](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html#page-segmentation-method) which is:

> Assume a single uniform block of text.

The result will be:

```
34 DUA34
```

Code:

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

# Load the image
img = cv2.imread("vHQ5q.jpg")

# Convert to the gray-scale
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# OCR
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(gry, config="--psm 6"))

# Display
cv2.imshow("", gry)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

You should know the [Page segmentation method](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html#page-segmentation-method).

I've got the result using pytesseract-version-[0.3.7](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/).

Comment: I used these functions to extract the plate. I gave you just the plate in the question to ask. Thanks for your reply, i will try it.

Comment: It worked. I changed the segmentation type.

Comment: Which segmentation type did you use and what is your tesseract version?

Comment: Tesseract version is 0.1.3. I used 6. segmentation mode like you.

Answer (score -1):

You can try PaddleOCR, they publish a license plate recognition model and also provide a training guide for license plate recognition.

link: https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/PaddleOCR/blob/dygraph/applications/%E8%BD%BB%E9%87%8F%E7%BA%A7%E8%BD%A6%E7%89%8C%E8%AF%86%E5%88%AB.md